# Why can't I return an anonymous object if calls to another object are used to construct it in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Pretty simple question. I have some assumptions why this doesn't work, but would like a more scholarly explanation.

This works:

```
newArray = oldArray.map(function(obj){
    return {'key': 'value'};
});
```

While this doesn't:

```
newArray = oldArray.map(function(obj){
    return {obj.key: obj.value};
});
```

Comment: Well, my first thought is that without some additional syntax, how would JavaScript know whether you mean for the property to be named "obj.key" or be named from the value contained within obj.key?

Comment: I couldn't find a similar question with a good answer. Maybe I just don't know the best search key words. Any suggestions @Quentin?

Comment: @adam0101 If that were the case I'd immediately see those values in the newly created array.

Comment: @Half_Duplex — Err… the link in the big yellow box at the top of the question?

Comment: @Half_Duplex, of course you wouldn't see those values as it's invalid syntax. I wasn't saying that's how it works. I was saying that what you want _can't_ work because of that. At least, not without additional syntax as is available in ECMA6. That's because `{a: 1}` and `{'a': 1}` are both valid means of declaring an object literal.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for adding a link to the correct answer, I don't believe it was there when I commented the first time and obviously my JS vernacular is lacking.

Comment: @Half_Duplex — It was added automatically by the system when the question was closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ECMA6 syntax you can do:

```
newArray = oldArray.map(obj => {
    return {[obj.key]: obj.value};
});
```

If you want to support older browsers, you will need to make a temporary object:

```
newArray = oldArray.map(function(obj) {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj[obj.key] = obj.value;
    return newObj;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to do it via

```
newArray = oldArray.map(function(obj){
    var foo = {};
    foo[obj.key] = obj.value;
    return foo;
});
```

There is a way to do what you want in ES6 with square brackets.